# Exporting .tiff georeferenced images in layout view using Python

Tags: arcpy, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, data-driven-pages

I have square grids of about 1000 polygons and i want to export TIFF images of  each grid using a Python script, am having this below Python which gives me only .tiff images without referenced

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for page_number in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = page_number
    print "Exporting page {0} of {1}".format(str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID), str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount))
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Temp\map_" + str(page_number) + ".tiff")

del mxd
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the georeferencing world file when you export your .tif image. Also, you haven't set the format correctly, this should be ".tif", not "tiff". Please see [ExportToTIFF documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttotiff.htm) for more information.

Try the below:

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Temp\map_{}.tif".format(page_number), world_file=True)
```

Comment: Dear MacroZED, thanks for your kind reply, it shows error if I run your script, please do elaborate on the world_file,

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: The string error is probably to do with the str(page_num). Did you incorporate the above into your code? or just run it on its own? If you try to run it on its one, it wont recognise the page_num. To test this, insert a page number instead of "page_num"...for eg try r"C:\Temp\map_1.tif" and see if it works.

Comment: mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for page_number in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = page_number
    print "Exporting page {0} of {1}".format(str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID), str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount))
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Users\LASA 27\Desktop\TST\Data Driven Pages" + str(page_number) + ".tif", world_file=True)

del mxd       this is what i did

Comment: the error says "keyboard interrupt", which means a user error, rather than a script error